# Different Excel versions give different results with xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, pdf, xlsxwriter

I'm creating pdfs by exporting from generated excel files using xlsxwriter for python. I tried to create a minimal example below from which my colleague and I get different results. I'm using the English version of Windows/Excel, Excel version 1810, while he is using Swedish version 1910.

In the resulting pdf "test.pdf" his page contains 43 rows of different height than mine, i.e. one does not fit the page, while mine shows all 44 rows. My guess is that our Excel versions interpret the files differently even though the settings seem to be the same, maybe the units for row height are different somehow? Is this a known problem?

```
import xlsxwriter
from win32com import client
import os

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

for n in range(44):
    ws.write(n,0,'test')

num_cols = 10
ws.set_v_pagebreaks([num_cols])
num_rows = 44
ws.set_h_pagebreaks([num_rows])
ws.fit_to_pages(1,1)
ws.set_paper(9)
ws.set_page_view()
ws.set_margins(0.2,0.2,0.5,0.3)
ws.set_footer('test')
for row in range(14*3+2):
    ws.set_row(row,17.85)
wb.close()
xlApp = client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(f'{os.getcwd()}\test.xlsx')
pdf = f'{os.getcwd()}/test.pdf'
wb.Worksheets[0].ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf)
wb.Close()
```

Comment: What happens if you take the XlsxWriter file, open it in Excel and the save it (to create an Excel file). Do you get the same results then in both versions of Excel then?

Comment: Yes, the Excel file is saved and when I open his file it looks like my own, but his Excel version shows fewer and larger rows.

Comment: In that case it isn't related to the fact that you created it with XlsxWriter, since it also happens with a file you create in Excel. I would suggest trying to create a sample file in Excel that displays the same on both systems and then create a similar one with XlsxWriter. If you can't dot that with Excel you won't be able to do it with XlsxWriter. Maybe look out for difference in units on the same system (inches vc cm) or different DPI. Also check if both have the same default font and font size.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your point before. Now I made an xlsx-file manually and sent it to my colleague, and that file now has the correct amount of rows. It is the xlsx-file generated by XlsxWriter that has different properties when generated on his computer.

Comment: This is probably a little bit too complicated to discuss in the comments. Open a XlsxWriter issue on GitHub and I will look into it.